# Null pointer on Kafka Spring Integration Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-kafka, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to implement a Spring Integration Flow using Kafka. But I am stuck with with the error.

When I debug, I see "HandlerAdapter handlerMethod" is null is `MessagingMessageListenerAdapter`. Not sure I am doing right here, or something more config required. But this is all I can find from documents and other pages. Any help is appreciated

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:255) ~[spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:80) ~[spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:51) ~[spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:923) [spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:903) [spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:729) [spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:615) [spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.cyclone.streams</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-poc</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!--Spring boot-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring Kafka-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--Other-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

And the code

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter())
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter() {
        KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter =
                new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(messageListenerContainer());
        kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(consumingChannel());
        return kafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel consumingChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> messageListenerContainer() {
        ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("order-graph-timeline-topic");
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
                new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer(consumerFactory(), containerProps);
        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group");//TODO
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "100");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "15000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return props;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `spring-integration-kafka-2.3.0.RELEASE` isn't compatible with the `spring-kafka-2.0.1.RELEASE`. As well as the Spring Boot `1.5.8.RELEASE` isn't compatible with that version.

Is there a strong reason to use Spring Kafka `2.0`? It was designed for the Spring `5.0` base line.

Consider to use Spring Kafka `1.3.1.RELEASE`. It is fully compatible with Apache Kafka `0.11`+, but at the same time it is compatible with the mentioned Spring Integration Kafka `2.3`.

Comment: Thanks. No reason to stick with a version. Doing a POC, so just picked the latest. So i changed spring-kafka and spring-integration-kafka to 1.3.1.RELEASE. What is the best spring boot version to use ?

Comment: No, `spring-integration-kafka` is still the same  - `2.3.0.RELEASE`. They are absolutely different artifacts. The Spring Boot is also still the same - `1.5.8.RELEASE`. Only what I suggest is to change your Spring Kafka to the `1.3.1.RELEASE`. That's it.

Comment: But Spring Kafka should never throw an NPE. Please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Not related to above, I am trying to use AckMode.MANUAL with IntegrationFlow. I am not finding a way to set Acknowledgment myself. The listener is initialized by the channel adapter. Any help is appreciated. And is there a good sample implementation which you can refer me  ?

Comment: The `Acknowledgment` is a `KafkaHeaders.ACKNOWLEDGMENT` header in the message produced by the `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. But I don't see `AckMode.MANUAL` in your code. Although that is indeed a separate question.